# Form Controller Values are Empty

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**Solved**
I am having trouble with the values of my form controller. When I submit the form, they stay as empty strings. I suspect that I may have made a mistake on the HTML side of things.

Here is the `register.component.ts` file:

```js
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  registerFormGroup: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        userName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      },  
    );
  }

  submitted: boolean = false;
  async onSubmit(user: User) {
    this.submitted = true;
    debugger;

    if (this.registerFormGroup.invalid) return;

    const result: Create_User = await this.userService.create(user);
    if (result.succeeded) result.message, 'User registration successful.';
    else result.message, 'User registration not successful.';
  }
}
```

And here is the `register.component.html` file:

```html
<div class="register-form">
  <div class="register-form-box">
    <div class="register-form-header" class="form-group">
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="registerFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerFormGroup.value)">
      <div class="input-text">
        <input type="text" formControlerName='userName' class="form-control" id="userName"
          placeholder="Enter Username" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted}" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

**Solved**
I realized that somehow I changed the html codes and that's why it's not working

Its should be like

formControlName='userName'

Instead of

formControlerName='userName'

Comment: What is definition of your User type?

Comment: It's a class export class User {
  userName: string;
  steamId: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
}

Answer (score -1):

Made some tests and couldn´t replicate the error, data does reach onSubmit function correctly. I would suspect that the issue is possibly caused by mismatch in object properties between form values ({userName: 'asdasd'}) and user interface (presumably {name: string}).

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: It points to possible cause of the issue, so it either an answer or a deleted/edited answer.  Can you confirm that expected value does not reach onSubmit function?

Comment: Expected values does not reach onSubmit its like user = {username: ''}

Comment: Please leave an answer for posterity